# Constructing Objects and Calling Member functions

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyTestClass
{
    int MyTestIVar;

    public: 
        MyTestClass(void);
        int firstCallMethod(void);
        int secondCallMethod(void);
};

MyTestClass::MyTestClass(void)
{
    MyTestIVar = 4;
}
int MyTestClass::firstCallMethod(void)
{
    return secondCallMethod();
}
int MyTestClass::secondCallMethod(void)
{
    return MyTestIVar;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyTestClass mTC;
    cout << mTC.firstCallMethod() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If use use

```
MyTestClass mTC();
```

instead it will disallow me to call any member functions and display this error

> ./experiment.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   ./experiment.cpp:31:14: error: request for member ‘firstCallMethod’ in
>   ‘mTC’, which is of non-class type ‘MyTestClass()’

I read the posts on value-initialize etc, but this error still doesn't seem logical to me. Why would this affect member functions?

And help greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you *sure* this code example is enough to reproduce the error? Also do you mean that if you replace the line "MyTestClass mTC;" with "MyTestClass mTC();" only then the error occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyTestClass mTC();
```

Does not declare an object of the `MyTestClass` class, as you think.

It Actually, declares a function by the name of `mTC` which does not take any parameters and returns an `MyTestClass` object.

This is known as the **[Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)** in c++.

Comment: Weird, isn't that an error on the parsers fault though because in c++ you can't declare functions within functions? Or is only you can't define a function within a function?

Comment: @rubixibuc: It's one of the strange dark corners of C++,Which you only get to know when you get bitten by it & believe me most of us who know it have been bitten by it :)

Answer (score 3):

You have stumbled upon the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

The line

```
MyTestClass mTC();
```

is parsed as a function prototype of a function named `mTC` which has no arguments and returns an instance of `MyTestClass`.