# Setting constructor default values in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, default, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)
>   [Constructing Objects and Calling Member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892558/constructing-objects-and-calling-member-functions)

Recently I've learnt a bit about constructors but today i've been having trouble setting default values for the constructor parameter.

The constructor declaration in the hpp file looks like this:

```
class PlayingCard {
public:
    PlayingCard(int value = 0, int suit = 0); //default values supplied
```

and the definition in the cpp file looks like this:

```
PlayingCard::PlayingCard(int value, int suit) :  _faceValue(value), _suit(suit)
{}
```

(`_faceValue` and `_suit` are private members of PlayingCard)
When i go to test this like so:

```
PlayingCard card1();
PlayingCard card2(7, 1);

cout << "suit int value: " << card1.getSuit() <<
        " face value: " << card1.getFaceValue() << endl;
cout << "suit int value: " << card2.getSuit() <<
        " face value: " << card2.getFaceValue() << endl;
```

card2 works fine, if i comment out the code in relation to card1.
Otherwise i get the error:
**request for member 'getSuit' in 'card1', which is of non-class type 'PlayingCard()'.**

Which must mean it doesn't recognized use of the constructor without arguments? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PlayingCard card1();
```

does not declare an object, it declares  function.
It declares an function named `card1` which takes no parameters and return an object of the type `PlayingCard`.

To declare an object you should do:

```
PlayingCard card1;
```

This is known as **[Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)** in C++.
I am answering this second time today. Vexing Parse day it seems!

Comment: uhh haha thank you very much, i'm with it now..

Answer (score 1):

```
PlayingCard card1();
```

this creates an ambiguity as this can be treated as a function prototype with return type PlayingCard and signature card1 with zero arguments. Better you remove the () after card1 and see.